# Expression is not a method in Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem for this code. lstTotal is the error. It says Expressions is not a method for the lstTotal. Im not very knowledgable in coding yet so any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub UpdateTotal()
    ' Clear the previous subtotal, tax and total
    lstTotal.Items.Clear()
    ' Compute and display the subtotal
    lstTotal.Items.Add("SUB TOTAL = ")(subtotal.ToString("C"))
    ' Compute and Display the tax
    Tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE
    lstTotal.Items.Add("   TAX=" & Tax.ToString("C"))
    ' Compute and display the total
    lstOrderReceipt.Items.Add("---------------")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make sense:

```
lstTotal.Items.Add("SUB TOTAL = ")(subtotal.ToString("C"))
```

Presumably you mean this:

```
lstTotal.Items.Add("SUB TOTAL = " & subtotal.ToString("C"))
```

The error message is saying that you are doing this:

```
Expression(subtotal.ToString("C"))
```

which is how you would call a method but what you have in place of `Expression`, i.e. `lstTotal.Items.Add("SUB TOTAL = ")` does not evaluate to a method so your code doesn't make sense.